# How can I animate an image from one point to another programmatically using a WPF canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, point

I am working on a WPF Application. In this app, I need to move my train on a railway. I drew all the railway lines on a canvas. So I just need to move the trains.

I also searched the Internet and I found [that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-the-position-of-an-object-by-using-pointanimation)! example.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SDKSamples
{
// This example shows how to use PointAnimation to animate the
// position of an ellipse by animating the Center property of an 
// EllipseGeometry. PointAnimation is used because the Center property
// takes a Point value.
public class PointAnimationExample : Page
{
    public PointAnimationExample()
    {

        // Create a NameScope for this page so that
        // Storyboards can be used.
        NameScope.SetNameScope(this, new NameScope());

        EllipseGeometry myEllipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry();
        myEllipseGeometry.Center = new Point(200, 100);
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusX = 15;
        myEllipseGeometry.RadiusY = 15;

        // Assign the EllipseGeometry a name so that
        // it can be targeted by a Storyboard.
        this.RegisterName(
            "MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry", myEllipseGeometry);

        Path myPath = new Path();
        myPath.Fill = Brushes.Blue;
        myPath.Margin = new Thickness(15);
        myPath.Data = myEllipseGeometry;

        PointAnimation myPointAnimation = new PointAnimation();
        myPointAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

        // Set the animation to repeat forever. 
        myPointAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        // Set the From and To properties of the animation.
        myPointAnimation.From = new Point(200, 100);
        myPointAnimation.To = new Point(450, 250);

        // Set the animation to target the Center property
        // of the object named "MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry."
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(myPointAnimation, "MyAnimatedEllipseGeometry");
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(
            myPointAnimation, new PropertyPath(EllipseGeometry.CenterProperty));

        // Create a storyboard to apply the animation.
        Storyboard ellipseStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        ellipseStoryboard.Children.Add(myPointAnimation);

        // Start the storyboard when the Path loads.
        myPath.Loaded += delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ellipseStoryboard.Begin(this);
        };

        Canvas containerCanvas = new Canvas();
        containerCanvas.Children.Add(myPath);

        Content = containerCanvas;
    }

}
```

}

I tried this code and its works. But when I run the application, the roads I drew before no longer appear. So how can I move my trains on my railway?

Comment: Instead of showing some working code you found on the internet show us *your* code and explain which parts of it you have problems with. Note also that the code you found is far too complicated. You don't need a Storyboard to animate the Center of an EllipseGeometry.

Comment: And if a train object is supposed to be animated along a railway, you would certainly use a [PointAnimationUsingPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-an-object-along-a-path-point-animation).

Comment: Fixed to read more clearly in English while maintaining original intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i continued to searching and i found the solution. 
I used to DoubleAnimation instance. 
The working code is below.

```
        public void move( Image target, double oldX, double oldY, double newX, 
        double newY,int time)
        {
        TranslateTransform trans = new TranslateTransform();
        target.RenderTransform = trans;

        DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(oldY, newY, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));
        anim1.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, anim1);

        DoubleAnimation anim2 = new DoubleAnimation(oldX, newX, 
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));
        anim2.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        trans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, anim2);
    }
```